# How to place the language switch in the main menu bar?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

The language switch appears on the bottom of the page.

How can I move it to the main menu?

Comment: Did you move the language switcher block to the main menu? It is in the _How to_ of the [Language Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_switcher) module page.

Comment: The article doesn't say how to put it in the menu. It talks about placing it in the side bar. Do I also have to add info to the Appearance page?

Answer (score 0):

Check your **page.tpl file** and check where it is, OR, you can check the **list of blocks in your site** to see where it is placed and move it to your desire position